# Cannot remove virtualenv directory from PC

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've tried `rm -rf venvpc` and I get the error message:

```
rm: cannot unlink `venvpc/Scripts/python.exe': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `venvpc/Scripts': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove directory `venvpc': Directory not empty
```

I removed the virtualenv name 'venvpc' from PyCharm in case there was a link there.

I tried removing via Windows Explorer and it says the folder or a file in it is open in another program.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it as root user , so use `sudo` (on linux) :

```
sudo rm -rf venvpc
```

and if you are in windows run `runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd` to command as admin.

Comment: `'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`  I'm on Windows and I'm an admin since it's my own PC.